# Run Time Error 13 “Type Mismatch" when using ActiveSheet.Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting-

> Run Time Error 13 “Type Mismatch"

at this line of code.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(sheetRange).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=(myAry), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

`myAry` is an an array which contains string.

`sheetRange` gets its value as following  -

```
lastRow = TotalRowsBeforeFilter()
    startRowNum = 1
    Let sheetRange = "A" & startRowNum & ":" & "E" & lastRow
```

Where am I doing wrong? I do not get this error on Excel 2016,  but in Excel 2013 I am getting this error.

Comment: And what does the string var sheetRange contain when it crashes? Look in the Locals window.

Comment: Also consider to reference the sheet by it's name eg `Worksheets("SheetName")`. Using `ActiveSheet` is not very reliable because `ActiveSheet` can be any sheet and is not necessarily the desired one.

Comment: Well that doesn't look like a worksheet range address so that would be your problem.

Comment: @Jeeped, I will give you the column which I am interested in  - It contains 
sheetRange(4,5)         Value:"Some String"      Type: "Variant/String"

Comment: @PEH - The Worksheet Name is not fixed, it will change each time. I have just one sheet.

Comment: *Some String* is not a valid range address.

Comment: @Jeeped  - In **Value** it is showing me the actual string which is in Row 4 and Column 5

Comment: Can you please tell the result of `Debug.Print sheetRange` right before the error line.

Comment: @PEH - The actual error is a _Run time Error 13 "Type Mismatch"_
`Debug.Print sheetRange` gives me `A1:S1987`

Comment: @aliza `A1:S1987`? Thats not possible with that code `Let sheetRange = "A" & startRowNum & ":" & "E" & lastRow`. Please clarify! Make sure everything in your question is correct!

Comment: Oops, my bad there was a typo - 'A1:E1987` is the correct one. It shows an address..

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: `myAry = Array("aa", "bb", "cc"): ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1987").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=(myAry), Operator:=xlFilterValues` works like intended if there is data in that range. Must be something wrong with your array maybe? Please show the code how your array is declared and filled with data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - I did not declare the `Dim MyAry() as String` instead I left it as Variant Type. When I declared MyAry as String, it worked. Strange though EXCEL 2016 does not have these issues.